# How to add to win forms app Listbox menu after right click event

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this function who catch right click

```
    private void listBoxFiles_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStripListBox.Show((Control)sender, e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample in the docs for [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button.aspx):

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    ...do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to add an entry to a listbox?

Use:

```
ListBox.Items.Add("My content here");
```

If you want to change the context menu for the right click action, have a look at this guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984319%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: i want each right click on item in my listbox will open a menu (delete, show statistics...)

Comment: ListBox.Items.Add("My content here") will ad an entry but i want menu which open several option and each click on item from this menu option will implement different function

Comment: i added contextMenuStrip (see my update), how can i insert values to the menu ? and how to make the file who right click become marked (color blue) ?

Comment: and another one: when i choose option from my menu hot to separate each option to different function ?

Comment: It's all there on the guide I posted.